# Analyzing data for a member's conversations

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, discord.py

I have a discord bot that is analyzing the positivity of every user's conversations within a discord server. I want to find a way to add all the results of instances where a user has gotten a rating on their message, and then find their average positivity within say like a period of an hour.

here is my code...

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    with open('data.txt', 'a') as f:
        positivity = {}

        member = message.author
        response = requests.post('http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/', {
            'text': message.content
        }).json()
        pos = response["probability"]["pos"]
        positivity[member] = pos

        for key, value in positivity.items():
            print(key, value, file=f)

        f.close()

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

The value for each messages positivity is referenced at...

pos = response["probability"]["pos"]

So now my only question is how can I pull an individual members total sum of positive ratings of all their messages and then average it out.

Just for reference, the

```
for key, value in positivity.items():
        print(key, value, file=f)
```

Prints out as something like:

EnzoWork#8248 0.46118706992711267
(it is a rating out of a scale of 0-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing the file would require reading it, summing the entries for that user, and then dividing that by the number of such entries:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def positivity(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    query_name = str(user)
    total = lines = 0
    with open('data.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            if not line.strip():  # skip blank lines
                continue
            name, amount = line.split()
            if name == query_name:
                total += float(amount)
                lines += 1
    if lines:
        await bot.say("Average positivity for {} is {}".format(user.mention, total/lines))
    else:
        await bot.say("Could not find entries from that user.")
```

For something like this, I'd recommend you start capturing more data about each message and begin using a database to store it.  You can then more easily do complex searches and aggregations across your dataset. I'd also recommend using ids to represent users instead of their names.

Comment: I am getting, discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Comment: Should I change discord.User to discord.User.id and just call "#positivity *id*"

Comment: @EnzoRomano does your file have some blank lines?  You can add an `if line:` to filter those out

Comment: So it did have blank lines, but now I have cleared them and my bot only will call the else of the if/else function.... even though there are 20 values for the member I am calling

Comment: @EnzoRomano Try changing `discord.User` to `discord.Member` in the above, they may be converted to strings differently.

Comment: Still getting the same result, i am thinking there is a problem with the query_name, the data for ratings is stored as "EnzoWork#8248 0.4215455813965004", and the EnzoWork#8248  is referenced as the key in my positivity dict... can I change anything in the "if name == query_name:"? Just trying to brainstorm sorry

Comment: Try printing out `query_name`? Is should be the `name#discriminator`. https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/user.py#L70

Comment: My result from the print is <class 'discord.member.Member'>

Comment: @EnzoRomano my brain is turned off today apparently.  That should be `str(user)`, not `str(discord.Member)`

Comment: So everything works awesome, thank you so much! and i'm sure you are busy but would you mind explaining some of the functionality. I understand the command and calling a discord.Member and that doesn't confuse me, but I do not 100% understand the line split? I am definitely going to also do some research myself though

Comment: @EnzoRomano `str.split` with no arguments splits a sting into a list on the whitespace. See the documentation for a longer explanation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split